# Why does Android app rolls back to a previous version after device shutdown?

Tags: android

Observed this very strange behavior with Android application. Approximate scenario:

1. Version A installed on the device
2. Application works alright
3. Version B installed on the device (B > A)
4. Application works alright
5. Device shuts down due to battery drain
6. Device turned on
7. Version A of the application runs on the device again

Additional info:

- The application isn't distributed through Google Play, but installed on-premise via USB connection (NOTE: the application runs in production; it's not installed through AndroidStudio).
- Kiosk
- Android 5.1 (API 22)

I guess I've got two questions:

- Why the device cached the older version of the APK (and where did it cache it)?
- Under which circumstances can applications roll back to previous versions like that?

**Edit (more information):**

- It looks like after the APK is rolled back, the application loses some permissions (maybe even all). Functionality that worked before the roll-back stops working due to SecurityException being thrown from Android's APIs. This happens even though this version of Android doesn't have runtime permissions yet!
- After browsing tablet's filesystem, I indeed see several app's APKs residing under similar paths: `/data/app/com.myapp-2/base.apk`, `/data/app/com.myapp-3/base.apk`, etc.

My current hypothesis is that battery drain causes the tablet to "reset" its state (for example, the clock is also reset), and when it's powered again it confuses between app's APKs and loads the wrong one.

However, I have no clue why would it do that, or how to prevent this behavior.

Comment: I faced this behaviour also. maybe this occurs due to instant run as it splits the apk and restarting device break the process and rollbacks to previous version.

Comment: Are you using different users on these devices? Maybe a guest session to one?

Comment: This could be device-specific (default cache settings). Have you tested on other devices?

Comment: Did you test it on the android emulator?

Comment: @TaslimOseni, there is one specific model of tablet used for in-field deployment. In addition, it's not something that reproduces easily. We saw it just once in the lab.

Comment: Alright, I just answered your question. Kindly let me know if the suggestion worked.

Answer (score 3):

> Why the device cached the older version of the APK (and where did it cache it)?

The trick here is in the version code. When you install a new version, **make sure the new version has a different version code**. The Android OS uses version codes to differentiate between different versions of the same APK so, this would work.

It's not really clear why this rollback happens. This is obviously a strange device-specific problem but nonetheless, a ton of factors could be responsible including the device's default installer, storage/cache settings, device memory, viruses, etc.

Comment: We still haven't figured the problem, but since your answer is the only one that could, theoretically, be related, the bounty is yours!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android Studio 3.5+, then instead of instant run, you are likely using Apply Changes.

This has a different way of shipping changes to the device, without rewriting the apk, so make a lot of sense that after rebooting, the apk that you will run if you execute your app directly on the device, has nothing to do with the one that was running before

> **Apply Changes**
>
> Instant Run and re-architectured and implemented from the ground-up a
>   more practical approach in Android Studio 3.5 called Apply Changes.
>   Apply Changes uses platform-specific APIs from Android Oreo and higher
>   to ensure reliable and consistent behavior; unlike Instant Run, Apply
>   Changes does not modify your APK.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/android-studio-35-project-marble-goes.html

Comment: This issue happens in production and the app isn't installed to devices through AndroidStudio. What do instant run or apply changes have to do with it?

Comment: oh, sorry, I assumed so since you mentioned "The application isn't distributed through Google Play, but installed on-premise via USB connection" so I automatically thought about Android Studio. After your update it is clear. I will think a bit more...

Answer (score 1):

This lists user installed packages:

```
adb shell cmd package help

pm list packages -f -U -3 --show-versioncode
```

And then fully uninstall before reinstalling:

```
adb uninstall com.myapp
```

With instant run and not applying the patch APK (see the `pm` help output), this might run the base APK. This does not roll-back anything, but it's likely the one APK without the other one APK overloaded (Android Studio might automate the application of the hot-patch, but at boot time this might not be the case). Not using instant run removes these patch update APK; and when there is only one APK, there is nothing else to run.

Comment: Sorry, don't see how this answers any of my questions. I can also go and manually erase these files through ADB, but, at this point, I want to understand why this happens.

Comment: @Vasiliy likely because Dalvik VM is handling instant run patch APK differently. The actual question is, why there are even two different instances of supposedly the same thing in different versions?

Comment: I'm not sure what instant run has to do with all this. The APKs weren't installed through AndroidStudio. As you say, one of the questions is "why there are multiple instances of APKs for the same app", but I don't see how your answer answers it...

Comment: @Vasiliy there shouldn't be multiple APK to begin with - and if, then the patch APK must be applied. There is a difference in between "apply changes" and boot time.