# Why does release android apk are rolls back to play store version after certain time

Tags: android, android-studio

Noticed this very strange behavior with my android application

- Installed app from play store with version name 3.1 App is working
  fine.
- Due to new correction,I've installed App via USB connection or    by
  sharing apk files with same version name.
- App is working fine with newly added features but
- After certain time/days i found that the newly added feature is
  gone and I'm using the play store version...

Additional info:

```
The same issue occurred in android version 11,12,9  followed by the above process.
```

However, I have no idea why would it is happening and how to prevent this behavior.

visited this below link for the similar issue and found nothing related to my issue.

[Why does Android app rolls back to a previous version after device shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542904/why-does-android-app-rolls-back-to-a-previous-version-after-device-shutdown/72545018#72545018)

Comment: Downgrading apps (higher versionCode to lower versionCode) is not possible on Android without losing the app data. Therefore if the app changes the new app version must have a higher versionCode than the old, but versionCode is invisible for users. Some apps use prefix number for versionCode for different app variants (e.g. for smartphone and tablets or other hardware). May be you had installed a newer versions with a lower versionCode because it was for different hardware. And then it was replaced with a better suiting version with a lower version but a higher versionCode.

Comment: If you really want to know what is happening name the apps and use tools to read out their `AndroidManifest.xml` look at the `versionCode` and post them together with the app name/packageName.

Comment: Hello @Robert thank you for responding,
I've installed released apk with same version name available in play store.
Getting this error from my colleagues device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the solution for this Silly Issue.**

from last one month i observed that my release apk which is not in production but has the same version name was auto updated to production version i it is for all the apk user.
I tried to disable the of google play store setting of auto update and after few day is not replaced by the production version.

:)

Answer (score 1):

My guessing is your play store has a function that called update automatically which is opend,your apk on Phone is version behind the play store version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But is it possible to update the app with same version name from play store ?
i don't think so.

Comment: @watson_wong Yes you were right about play store feature.